# Publishing pages is getting failed in Committing Deployment phase

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

Publishing of pages is getting failed with the below error

> Phase: Deployment Commit Phase failed,
>
> Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560,
>
> Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560,
>
> Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560,
>
> Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560, Unable to commit transactions, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560, Commit failed for transaction: tcm:0-288346-66560

The pages were successfully published till yesterday. We have not changed anything on content delivery servers.

Comment: There would have something triggered from y'day to today. Did you check your license file is valid, might have expired today? Also, please do post the exception trace from your deployer log (enable debug if needed) as this error message does not provide much value.

Comment: Can you please try to enable root logging (<root level="DEBUG">) or Hibernate logging on the deployer? Then check exactly what's the Hibernate stack-trace generated. This should give you more info.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to work from the starting point that *something* changed in your content delivery systems, even if at the moment you don't know what or why. This means you should go back to basics and check all the things that might cause a publish transaction to be unable to deploy successfully.

My first guess would be that it's a permissions problem. How is security managed on your content delivery server? What account is running the deployment process? (are you using a service, or a web application?) Are the file system permissions for that account correctly set, and is the account itself still valid. (Looking for something that might change due to outside influences - perhaps the account was set to expire - yes I know you wouldn't do that deliberately...)